# Removing dataframe rows containing a certain type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> d
Out[28]: 
                         A                     B      C      D       E
2017-06-08 20:39:00 1260.00  1903-08-12 00:00:00 230.00 245.00 19954.55
2017-06-08 20:40:00 1260.00                 1330 230.00 245.00 19966.51
2017-06-08 20:48:00 1260.00                 1320 230.00 240.00 19961.00
2017-06-08 21:02:00 1240.00                 1330 230.00 245.00 19951.38
2017-06-08 21:06:00 1240.00                 1340   5.00 240.00 19966.84
2017-06-08 21:07:00 1240.00                 1350 220.00 230.00 20000.24
2017-06-08 21:08:00 1250.00                 1370 220.00 230.00 20004.66
2017-06-11 20:31:00 1220.00                 1280 235.00 245.00 19913.86
```

I want to remove all the values (except in column A) that are of type datetime.datetime (here the first one in column B). I tried the following but didn't work (intention was to convert datetime to nan and remove nan values later):

```
d[type(d)==pd.datetime]=np.nan
```

I also tried this with each individual columns , i.e. the following:

```
df=d['B'].copy()
df[type(df)==pd.datetime]=np.nan
```

Comment: This is not possible because the datetime of the column is probably 'O'.

Comment: Do you want to replace them with something or drop them completely?

Comment: Thanks, I want to drop them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `boolean indexing` is not sufficient. You'll need to check the datetime for each item.

Input:

```
In [239]: df
Out[239]: 
                  Col1                 Col2
0  1903-08-12 00:00:00                    1
1                    1                  abc
2                    2                    2
3                 1234                 1234
4                  abc  1903-08-12 00:00:00
```

---

**Option 1**

Using `df.apply` and `pd.to_datetime`, followed by `df.isnull` and `boolean indexing`. Use `df.dropna` to drop rows with `NaN`.

```
In [290]: df[df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').isnull()].dropna()
Out[290]: 
   Col1  Col2
1     1   abc
2     2     2
3  1234  1234
```

---

**Option 2**

A direct application of `pd.datetime` (not using `df.apply`):

```
In [57]: df[pd.to_datetime(df.stack(), 'coerce').unstack().isnull()].dropna()
Out[57]: 
   Col1  Col2
1     1   abc
2     2     2
3  1234  1234
```

---

**Option 3**

Using `df.mask` (thank you piRSquared!)

```
In [62]: df.mask(pd.to_datetime(df.stack(), 'coerce').notnull().unstack()).dropna()
Out[62]: 
   Col1  Col2
1     1   abc
2     2     2
3  1234  1234
```

---

**Option 4**

You can use `df.applymap`

```
In [240]: df[~df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.datetime))].dropna()
Out[240]: 
   Col1  Col2
1     1   abc
2     2     2
3  1234  1234
```

Comment: @piRSquared Can't figure out how to call it... x( Answer please?

Comment: Thanks, i found another solution posted below. You guys think that has some downside?

Comment: `df.mask(pd.to_datetime(df.stack(), 'coerce').notnull().unstack())`

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you! I understood how it works, and it actually gave me an idea for another option.

Comment: @dayum Yes, see my comment on that. I've provided 4 options here, all work. If it's fine for you, you can mark it accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, not sure if this is the best one.

```
df= d.iloc[:,1:].convert_objects(convert_dates=False,convert_numeric =True)
df.dropna()
```

Comment: Yes, this has a downside because 1. it is deprecated 2. it converts strings and fails, so they become NaN too.